# pasar item's de un ListBox a otro con DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente problema, en un formulario Aspx con C#, necesito agregar o eliminar items a un ListBox desde otro ListBox, que se encuentran seleccionados en uno, en ambos listBox se alimentan con DataSource(), he visto en internet y los que pude encontrar los items se agregan con .Items.Add()

Después de realizar los movimientos de item's debo tener un boton para grabar los cambios.-

Se agradece la ayuda.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para implementar lo que plantes deberias conservar la listas que carga los listbox en el objeto `Session`, entonces operando en memoria puedes mover los items de una lista a otra

[[ASP.NET] – Pasar valores entre dos GridView](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2010/03/aspnet-pasar-valores-entre-dos-grisview.html)

En el articulo implemento esto que comento, solo que en lugar de ListBox uso GridView, pero la tecnica que tienes que lograr es la misma.

- Recuperas las listas de Session
- Localizas el valor seleccionado (te puedes ayudar con linq)
- Agregar en la lista de seleccion
- Eliminas de la lista de origen
- Asignas los DataSource para ver reflejado el cambio

Comment: Estimado Leandro me parece perfecta tú comentario voy a realizar unas pruebas y comento como me fue, estaba realmente perdido como hacerlo y antes ya había trabajado con session y ahora no se me había ocurrido.